# The code "new Handler()" always returns null in Android

Tags: android, android-handler

I create an instance of "Handler" in Android using a simple line of code like:

```
Handler mTHandler = new Handler();
```

The problem is that when I check with the debugger, even when the instance is successfully created, I always get "null", but even when the value of the object is "null" I am able to call methods of the class such as:

```
mTHandler.handleMessage(new Message());
```

The main problem is when I try to assign a callback to mTHandler like:

```
if (mTHandler != null) {
  mTHandler.post(new Runnable...)
}
```

and the callback is never registered since the instance is always "null". My questions are:

1. Why the object is shown as "null" and it is actually "null" while an instance is actually created for it?
2. How can make sure that the object is valid before registering a callback? More specifically in this case.

Thanks for your help,

Dan

Comment: What happens if you do not do a null check? I use handler.post directly without null check.

Comment: Then it will work and my unit tests will pass with the expected coverage but I need to find out why this happens. The code cannot be in production then.

Comment: I think the null check is not required. Because the handler is created to communicate with the UI Thread, I see you using post.

Comment: If it's null and it can be called, then it must be your project build. Try rebuilding it.